# Django - Saving ModelForm with foreign key from other model

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm creating a Poll app with these models

```
class Poll(BaseModel):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  end_date = models.DateField()

class Choice(BaseModel):
  poll = models.ForeignKey('Poll')
  choice = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  index = models.IntegerField()
```

A poll can have many choices -- the amount will vary for each poll. I'm struggling to figure out how to save a Poll through a modelform and at the same time save its related Choices.

I know I have to override the Save and Clean methods in my PollForm, but after that it kind of gets convoluted. I know there's a more pythonic/djangoesque way of doing this. My main confusion is the relationship between Choice and Poll, because it's only defined in one direction.

Additionally, I can't figure out how this would work when updating a Poll with a set of choices where some exist and some are new. The below code does not work, of course, but it's how I'm approaching thinking about this. I would appreciate a nudge in the right direction!

```
class PollForm:
  def save(self, choices, commit=True, *args, **kwargs):

    poll = super(PollForm, self).save(commit=False, *args, **kwargs)

    if commit:

      p = poll.save()

      for choice in choices:
        choice['poll_id'] = p.id

        if choice['id']:
          c = ChoiceForm(choice, instance=Choice.objects.get(id=choice['id']))
        else:
          c = ChoiceForm(choice)

        if c.is_valid():
          c.save()

    return poll
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is Django Formsets (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/), specifically: Model Formsets (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets).
For your model, you must use an inline formset (for the Choice model).
You can find all the information about them in: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets.

Hope this helps.